# OCaml checking if an element exists on the right-hand side of a tuple

Tags: list, tuples, ocaml, type-inference

I'm currently trying to implement a type inference algorithm (unification algorithm) using the OCaml language. I faced some implementation-wise difficulties and was hoping someone would be kind enough to give me some help.

Let me give some background information of what I'm trying to implement.

```ocaml
[(TypeVar "t1", TypeFunc (TypeVar "t2", TypeVar "t3"))]
```

This `(type * type) list` type is a way to express an equality, such that type `t1` is mapped to a function of `t2 -> t3`.

What I'm trying to capture is the case where the type variable on the left-hand side of the equality also occurs on the right-hand side, which would lead to the algorithm failing. To elaborate, if we would have

```ocaml
[(TypeVar "t1", TypeFunc (TypeVar "t1", TypeVar "t3"))]
```

this would give us an error, since `t1 = t1 -> t3` is a contradiction.

Here's the actual OCaml function that I tried to implement to catch this contradiction:

```ocaml
let contradiction_check (a, t) =
  List.exists (fun (x, _) -> x = a) t;;

let t1 = TypeVar "t1";;
let t2 = TypeFunc (TypeVar "t2", TypeVar "t3");;
```

The problem with this code is that first of all `t2` isn't a list, which would give us an error. However, this is intentional, since my objective is to take the tuple list `[(TypeVar "t1", TypeFunc (TypeVar "t2", TypeVar "t3"))]` and check if the left-hand side of the tuple occurs in the right-hand side.

I guess my specific question would be: Is it possible to implement the `List.exists` function as a version for tuples? I've tried manually writing functions but it seems to get more complicated than I initially thought.

It gets particularly complicated for examples such as:

```ocaml
[(TypeVar "t1", TypeFunc (TypeFunc (TypeVar "t2", TypeVar "t3"),
  TypeFunc (TypeVar "t1", TypeVar "t4")))]

(** t1 = (t2 -> t3) -> (t1 -> t4) **)
```

Any feedback is appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should just write a recursive function to search:

```
(** [is_free ~varname t] is [true] iff [varname] appears as a free type variable in [t] *)
let is_free ~varname =
  let rec r = function
    | TypeVar n when String.( = ) n varname -> true
    | TypeVar _ -> false
    | TypeFunc s t -> r s || r t
    | TypaApp c t -> r c || r t (* if c is just a name not a type you don’t want [r c] here *)
    | TypeForall n t -> 
      if String.( = ) n varname
      then false
      else r t
  in
  r
```

I don’t know what all your cases look like but you will write a function something like the above.

Then to see if you can unify things:

```
let can_unify = function
  | TypeVar t1, TypeVar t2 when String.( = ) t1 t2 -> (* decide what to do here *)
  | TypeVar varname, t -> not (is_free ~varname t)
  | _ -> (* throw an error or fix your types so this case can’t happen *)
```

You can now achieve what you want with familiar list functions.